# Open Bootstrap Model and Load load iframe with one button

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I need a button to open both "Bootstrap Modal" and Load iframe.

for now i have following concept: 
User click on Modal Button Modal opens and then user need to click on another button in the Modal to load the iframe.

i found some solutions, but most of them using javascript with url in it. in my case i cant use this because i get the url from a button where this button has a dynamic id that get generated by a shortcode. as well i cant add this shortcode in the javascript, i already tried.

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fileShareModal[wpv-post-id]">Open Modal</a>

<a class="btn btn-warning" href="[wpv-post-url]?layout_id=201" target="myiFrame[wpv-post-id]">click to load iframe</a>

<iframe name="myiFrame[wpv-post-id]" src="about:blank" class="max-h-600"></iframe>
```

I would like to get the dropdown-item button to open the modal and load the iframe. is that possible while keeping the structure of my urls the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can open modals with jquery: 
`

$(selector).modal("show");

`

So that means you can add an event to the button wich loads the iframe, and also open the modal

You need to add ids to each button:

`

```
$(idOfTheIframeLoader).click(e => 
    $(idOfModal).modal("show")
);
```

`

Comment: This is loading the iFrame but not opening the Modal. The modal has a dynamic id, is that the problem? this is the id of the modal :  fileShareModal[wpv-post-id]

Comment: I have changed the ID of the modal to "fileShareModal" and added the ID to the jQuery as well gave my button id="idOfTheIframeLoader" it works now but the problem its loading all the modals of the posts i have at once. i maybe forgot to mention i am using this in a loop.

Comment: If you are using it in a loop, you can do it like: `for (let i of $(yorurid).get()){ $(i).modal("show"); }`

Comment: And you can add a condition to it as well, note that i is a native html element, not a jquery object, thats why you need to do $(i)